# Redux Dispatch Is Looping When Success is true in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I Note have a state in redux like this:

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  success: false,
  error: null,
};
```

I have created CRUD API in the node backend.

I have two components in react

the first component is to add a new note to the database

which have a normal textarea input.

function in noteSlice.js is:

```
export const addNote = createAsyncThunk("addNote", async (data) => {
  try {
    await axiosInstance.post("/api/note/add", data);
    return "Note has been added";
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err.message;
  }
});
```

And in slice:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(addNote.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.success = false;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(addNote.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.success = true;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(addNote.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.success = false;
      state.error = payload;
    });

.../other cases
```

In Second Component I have displayed all notes by date sorting:

Which look like this:

```
const Note = ({ cardId }) => {
  const { loading, data, error, success } = useSelector((state) => state.note);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  function deleteNoteFn(id) {
    dispatch(deleteNote(id));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getNotesByCardId(cardId));
  }, [cardId, success]);

// returning html
```

Getting Note Function in slice

```
// GET DEAL
    builder.addCase(getNotesByCardId.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.success = false;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(getNotesByCardId.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.success = true;
      state.data = payload;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(getNotesByCardId.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.success = false;
      state.error = payload;
    });
```

### My main problem is in second component

when ever i add a new note. I want to reload all notes by success state which is shown in useeffect.

but the getNotesByCardId is also changing success state so useEffect creates the loop for this is code.

please help me thank you.

I have tried removing the success state changing from getNotesByCardId.fullfilled but i want this state to be there.

thank you in advance for your adivce

Comment: Just splitting your success state into a separate states (e.g. `addNoteSuccess` and `getNotesSuccess`) for each action in your Redux slice, should fix this, by letting you listen specifically for one action in your `useEffect`.

Comment: Please suggest me a the reference to fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 'success' in the dependency list of useEffect. Removing it should fix the issue.

Comment: no, because i want to dispatch on success to refetch the notes

Comment: I think in that case, you should slightly update your post async thunk. In addNote.fulfilled case, you should update the state with the newly added note. This way you will not have to re fetch the notes list again and your store will be always synced. This essentially means all CRUD done axios must be reflected in the store too